# Lazy loading of Blob properties of one class

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, blob

I want to lazy load of @Lob properties.
First ,i use javassist to instrument my class as described here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties:
Code:

My class contains "summary" and "title" properties those are Lob and other properties.
Code:

```
public class News extends BaseEntity{
   .
   .
   .
   @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
```

@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public String getTitle() {
        return title;
       }

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getPublishDate() {
    return publishDate;
}
```

.
   .
   .
}

First i load one news from database and want to retrieve publishdate of news(i write my codes in below)
Code:

```
newsDAO.findByid(1L).getPublishDate();
```

and findByid method is :

```
Code:
public News findById(Long id) throws ServiceException {
        News  entity = em.getReference(entityClass, id);
         return entity;
    }
```

then ,hibernate generates this query:
Code:

```
Hibernate:
    select
        news0_.id as id1_,
        news0_.entityVersion as entityVe2_1_,
        news0_.publishDate as publish15_1_,
        news0_.url as url1_
    from
        News news0_
    where
        news_.id=?
```

This query shows that ,it does not retrieve Lob property and fortunately lazy loading of Lob properties works well.

But when i load only "summary" property of news
Code:

```
newsDAO.findByid(1L).getSummary();
```

then ,hibernate generates these queries:
Code:

```
Hibernate:
    select
        news0_.id as id1_,
        news0_.entityVersion as entityVe2_1_,
        news0_.publishDate as publish15_1_,
        news0_.url as url1_
    from
        News news0_
Hibernate:
    select
        news_.summary as summary1_,
        news_.title as title1_
    from
        News news_
    where
        news_.id=?
```

I have two qurestions:
1.I only want to retrieve "summary" property not "title" property,but hibernate query shows that it also retrieve "title" property,Why this happens?
2.Why hibernate generates two query for retrieving only summary property of news?

I would be appreciate if anyone helps me.
Khosro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you enable "lazy fetching for propery"?  Unlike other lazy fetching, it is disabled by default
2. In your code, you called 2 method, so I guess hibernate generates 2 queries.
   How does the findById method look like?

Comment: For your first question:Yes,i instrument my class to lazy load of basic property(here Blob property) look at :http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties 
Your second question:
This is my code : 
 public News findById(Long id) throws ServiceException {
    return  em.getReference(News.class, id);

}

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is to make a separate Blob entity (which has just an id + data field) and reference it "one to one" with your Entity, so you can lazy load it without Problems